# I have this error on my console and can't understand it "console.error.apply(console, Object(r.d)(t))"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, getelementbyid

I have added this [jsfiddle iframe popup example](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/n86ad4L3/28/) to [my website](http://www.colline-vence.com/index3.php) but can't make it work properly. I can read 4 errors on my consol.

After some research I can say that the problem come from the Recaptcha div, when I delete this part of code from my development tool, all works fine. There is a way to delete it when the page is loaded ?

```
<div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="bottomright" style="width: 256px; height: 60px; display: block; transition: right 0.3s ease; position: fixed; bottom: 14px; right: -186px; box-shadow: gray 0px 0px 5px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="grecaptcha-logo"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LfMLuYUAAAAAObEEWN0DF3fjNDUuSZxWz38OTW1&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9zZWN1cmUucmVzZXJ2aXQuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=fr&amp;v=HYx6hBAtwYatsD8qzq7tXNTk&amp;size=invisible&amp;cb=chdx935d7511" width="256" height="60" role="presentation" name="a-lqv01fzesjs7" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-storage-access-by-user-activation"></iframe></div><div class="grecaptcha-error"></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-100000" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: You are loading the `reserveit.js` script before the HTML. So it tries to select an element that does not **yet** exist. Move that script to the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: you are right, now it give me another error and don't really understand where it come from !!

Comment: Update your question with the JS that throws that error and the error message statement.

Comment: done thank you, I don't know from where this error can come from ?

Comment: Well, that is not an error but a function call. Please update your descriptive text as well and add all the relevant resources (code, error, etc.) to the description.